# How to receive notifications from Firebase Cloud Messaging in React Native

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, firebase, react-native

I have a react native project and want to be able to receive notification from FCM. I have set up the project ( generated a google-services.json file for my project, modified the build.gradle files accordingly etc ) but so far I haven't been able to run the project. I am using React Native Firebase library https://rnfirebase.io/ but the experience is just not good so far. I've been stumbling from error to error like the one below:

```
Error: You attempted to use a firebase module that's not installed on your Android project by calling firebase.app().

Ensure you have:

1) imported the 'io.invertase.firebase.app.ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage' module in your 'MainApplication.java' file. 
2) Added the 'new ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage()' line inside of the RN 'getPackages()' method list.
```

I'm just done trying to get the tooling to work. Can you tell me what other approach I can take to get firebase notifications to work for a React Native project that doesn't make use of the library above ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed the suggestions in the error message? Also what could work is deleting the build and cache of your android project, and then rebuilding the application. What version of firebase you are using?

Comment: Hi, I already deleted the build directory and re-compiled the project. I went and check other posts and managed to get the project running but the app crashes immediately.  What I don't understand is why the following piece of code is failing even to say what's wrong:  

```messaging()
      .getToken()
      .then(token => {
        console.log(token);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });```

The messaging() function above is being imported from the @react-native-firebase/messaging package. It just